# How do I generate numbers according to a Soliton distribution?

Tags: distributions, python

The [Soliton distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soliton_distribution) is a discrete probability distribution over a set $\{1,\dots, N\}$ with the probability mass function

$$
p(1)=\frac{1}{N},\qquad p(k)=\frac{1}{k(k-1)}\quad\text{for }k\in\{2,\dots, N\}
$$

I'd like to use it as part of an implementation of an [LT code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luby_transform_code), ideally in Python where a uniform random number generator is available.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If we start at $k=2$, the sums telescope, giving $1-1/k$ for the (modified) CDF.  Inverting this, and taking care of the special case $k=1$, gives the following algorithm (coded in `R`, I'm afraid, but you can take it as pseudocode for a Python implementation):

```
rsoliton <- function(n.values, n=2) {
  x <- runif(n.values)         # Uniform values in [0,1)
  i <- ceiling(1/x)            # Modified soliton distribution
  i[i > n] <- 1                # Convert extreme values to 1
  i
}
```

As an example of its use (and a test), let's draw $10^5$ values for $N=10$:

```
n.trials <- 10^5
i <- rsoliton(n.trials, n=10)
freq <- table(i) / n.trials  # Tabulate frequencies
plot(freq, type="h", lwd=6)
```

[image: Frequency distribution]

Comment: For the related "robust" soliton distribution, you probably have to settle for a slightly less efficient solution (based on a binary search or the equivalent).

Answer (score 7):

## Python (adapted from [@whuber's R solution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/37583/14200))

```
from __future__ import print_function, division                                           
import random                                                                   
from math import ceil                                                           

def soliton(N, seed):                                                           
  prng = random.Random()                                                        
  prng.seed(seed)                                                                  
  while 1:                                                                         
    x = random.random() # Uniform values in [0, 1)                                 
    i = int(ceil(1/x))       # Modified soliton distribution                            
    yield i if i <= N else 1 # Correct extreme values to 1                         

if __name__ == '__main__':                                                         
  N = 10                                                                           
  T = 10 ** 5 # Number of trials                                                   
  s = soliton(N, s = soliton(N, random.randint(0, 2 ** 32 - 1)) # soliton generator                   
  f = [0]*N                       # frequency counter                              
  for j in range(T):                                                               
    i = next(s)                                                                    
    f[i-1] += 1                                                                    

  print("k\tFreq.\tExpected Prob\tObserved Prob\n");                               

  print("{:d}\t{:d}\t{:f}\t{:f}".format(1, f[0], 1/N, f[0]/T))                     
  for k in range(2, N+1):                                                          
    print("{:d}\t{:d}\t{:f}\t{:f}".format(k, f[k-1], 1/(k*(k-1)), f[k-1]/T))
```

### Sample Output

```
k   Freq.   Expected Prob   Observed Prob

1   9965    0.100000    0.099650
2   49901   0.500000    0.499010
3   16709   0.166667    0.167090
4   8382    0.083333    0.083820
5   4971    0.050000    0.049710
6   3354    0.033333    0.033540
7   2462    0.023810    0.024620
8   1755    0.017857    0.017550
9   1363    0.013889    0.013630
10  1138    0.011111    0.011380
```

### Requirements

The code should work in Python 2 or 3.

Comment: @whuber LT implementation now on [GitHub](https://github.com/alexchamberlain/socket/tree/master/fountain). Not perfect, but it's a start.