# How do I generate numbers according to a Robust Soliton distribution?

Tags: distributions, matlab, robust

I'm working on project in Matlab which aim is to demonstrate how Luby Transform codes work. I need to generate generation matrix and I need to get some values from Robust Soliton Distribution, can someone explain me how to generate numbers according to this distribution, I need to generate one value for each column in my matrix, I saw Robust Solition formula here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soliton_distribution#Robust_distribution but I don't understand what each variable means. Thanks in advance

Here is the formula form Wiki:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: These are not the formulas for the distribution: they are formulas for *corrections* to it.  The soliton distribution itself is discussed (with R and Python code) at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37581/how-do-i-generate-numbers-according-to-a-soliton-distribution.

Comment: While the two questions are related, the answers to the second question don't seem to answer this one, so I don't think this should be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this

Put the cumulative probabilities in a vector according to soliton : Vector P
then the variable

```
find(rand < P , 1,'first')
```

gives you your variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [inverse CDF method](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/273782/generate-random-number-from-a-specific-probability-mass-in-r). Note that you'll first need to normalize this distribution.